# calculate the memory of c++ map

Tags: c++, stl

A function is executed every 5 min.If the function is in the process, the memory of the process will reach 1.2G! If remove the function, the memory will be about 20M. The function is:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
MysqlData rset = mysql.queryRecord(sql);
map<string, int> temp;
for (size_t i = 0; i < rset.size(); i++) {
    const string& circleId = rset[i]["id"];
    const int category = strto<int>(rset[i]["subject"]);
    temp[circleId] = category;
}
if (!temp.empty()) {
    m_category.swap(temp); //m_category is global variable.
}
```

There are about 300,000 records in the db.The length of field id about 36 B, and the value of the field subject is a digit that ranges from 0 to 20. So the size of element is 40 B.
  Thus, in my opinion, the size of m_category is:
  40 * 300000 = 120，00，000 = 12M
  But 12M is much less than 1.2G! Why?
  BTW, I use the command top and the RES to see the memory of the process.
  How to calculate the memory of the map elements?

Comment: How much memory does the `reset` container use?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM info" - Why? Why select everything and process it in the application rather than adding appropriate "WHERE" clause and let the database narrow down the result set before transmitting it?

Comment: Why are you using `circleId` and `category` at all ? Just set the map directly `temp[rset[i]["id"]] = ... `

Comment: a) Possibly the class MysqlData - don't know where that comes from - isn't freeing the result set in its destructor, maybe it is an explicit operation you need to call? b) your estimate for the size of your map is low - the std::string for your field id will allocate heap memory for the string contents, there's a small amount of heap overhead for that but it shouldn't be a factor of 100.  Still, its something.  Why don't you try modifying the function so it never swaps temp <=> m_category, or even so that it doesn't even build the map temp.  Then you can see if it is the mysqldata or not.

Comment: If that doesn't work tell us where you got MysqlData from - it is one of the standard MySQL api wrappers or what?

Comment: Obviously some or all of your figures are wrong, or `MysqlData` is extremely inefficient. There's no way we can know from here.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up what others have commented above. The answer to your question is: you have a memory leak. And it is not in your function, it is inside the MysqlData class which you have failed to post here. So if you need further help you will have to provide all of us with all the information.

Comment: _"it is inside the MysqlData class which you have failed to post here"_ - Yeah because if you can't see it and can't examine it then it must be the culprit. I'm sure there's plenty of code in the OP's project that is suspect so why take such a narrow view on such an absolute?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - a) because the OP said that not calling this fucntion eliminated the problem so the problem is much more likely to be in the function than without, and b)because the MysqlData class is hiding one or more very large database operations and holding an entire recordset (this is obvious by looking at the code provided).  But actually, I don't think we're ever going to hear from the OP again: my bet is that this was not only his first appearance on SO, but also his last.  As happens often with first-time questions.